# How can I fix my JSON loading problem on my Android app?

Tags: java, android, mysql

My application keeps loading and doesn't go anywhere, the error code is [image: Error code]
I think it was the JSON, but I don't really know. I'm a beginner.

```java
progressDialog.show();
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(
    Request.Method.POST,
    Urls.LOGIN_URL,
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                String result = jsonObject.getString("status");

                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                if (result.equals("success")){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    for(int i = 0; i <jsonArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String name = object.getString("Name");
                        String email = object.getString("Email");
                        String phone = object.getString("Phone");

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,profileActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("name",name);
                        intent.putExtra("email",email);
                        intent.putExtra("phone",phone);
                        startActivity(intent);finish();
                        massage("User Login Successfully");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Kindly add full stacktrace as text not image .

Answer (score 0):

Json loading will throw exception if took longer.

you can use async task on **AppCompat Activity** to get json result

```
private class AsyncMsg extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(sndRecorder.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        //pdLoading.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            url = new URL("https://<your url address>.php?r=" + Math.round( Math.random()*10000000) );

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "exception1: " + e.toString();
        }
        try {
            // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
            conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            // setDoInput and setDoOutput method depict handling of both send and receive
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // Append parameters to URL
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                .appendQueryParameter("username", params[0])
                .appendQueryParameter("password", params[1])
                .appendQueryParameter("example", params[2])
                .appendQueryParameter("example2", params[3]);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            // Open connection for sending data
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return "exception 2r: " + e1.toString();
        }

        try {
            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            // Check if successful connection made
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                // Read data sent from server
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                return(result.toString());

            }else{

                return("unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "exception" + e.toString();
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "on post execute", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        
        if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("false"))
        {
            // If username and password does not match display a error message
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid email or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("exception") || result.equalsIgnoreCase("unsuccessful")) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OOPs! Something went wrong. Connection Problem." + result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            //UnknownHostException:
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sight: " + result + result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            String text = result;
            text = text.trim();
            String word = "UnknownHostException";
            if((text.lastIndexOf(word) > -1)||(text == "")) {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                return;
            }

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "url: " + url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   

            String jsonString = result;
            //populateListView(jsonString);
        }
    }
}
```